# widget delay and timeout

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-widget

This is a pretty general question. I made a flashlight application with widgets and 
it works, but:

1. The flash works fine, but the icon change image is delayed. Once you push the icon, the flashlight is turned on but the image is changed about 0.4 seconds later. **(solved by smaller images)**

**2. After a day, I check the widget and it doesn't work, but if I pull the widget again it works.**

What could make these things happen?

currentprovider.class

```java
public class CurrentProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static final String WIDGETTAG = "WidgetFlashLight";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        Log.i(WIDGETTAG, "onUpdate");

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Log.i(WIDGETTAG, "updating widget[id] " + appWidgetId);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CurrentService.class);
            intent.setAction(CurrentService.CHANGE_CAMERA_STATE);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetBtn, pendingIntent);
            Log.i(WIDGETTAG, "pending intent set");

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }   
}
```

currentService.class

```java
public class CurrentService extends Service {
    public static final String CHANGE_CAMERA_STATE = "ChangeState";
    public static  boolean mFlashIsOn = false;
    public static Camera camera;
    public static Parameters params;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_EX = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
     Notification notification;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        Log.i(CurrentProvider.WIDGETTAG, "onStartCommand");

        getCamera();
        switchCameraState(intent);

        stopSelf(startId);

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    private void switchCameraState(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(CurrentProvider.WIDGETTAG, "This is the intent " + intent);
        if (intent != null){
            String requestedAction = intent.getAction();
            Log.i(CurrentProvider.WIDGETTAG, "This is the action " + requestedAction);
            if (requestedAction != null && requestedAction.equals(CHANGE_CAMERA_STATE)){


                int widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 0);

                AppWidgetManager appWidgetMan = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),R.layout.widgetlayout);

                switchFlash(views);

                appWidgetMan.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
                Log.i(CurrentProvider.WIDGETTAG, "State updated!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void getCamera() {
        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }



    public void switchFlash(RemoteViews views) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            Log.i("camera||params","is null");
            return;
        }
        params = camera.getParameters();

        if (mFlashIsOn) {;
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widgetBtn, R.drawable.wi_off);
            mFlashIsOn=false;
            //setNotification(false);
            switchNotificationOff();
        }else{      
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widgetBtn, R.drawable.wi_on);
            mFlashIsOn=true;
            setNotification(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void setNotification(boolean x){

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Just FlashLight";

        notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, 0);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Just FlashLight";
        CharSequence contentText = "Press to stop flashlight";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, StartScreen.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
            0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, 
            contentText, contentIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_EX, notification);
    }

    public void switchNotificationOff( ){
        if (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE!=null) {
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
            nMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_EX);
        }
    }
}
```

providerInfo.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:minWidth="72dp" 
  android:minHeight="72dp" 
  android:updatePeriodMillis="0" 
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widgetlayout">
</appwidget-provider>
```

widgetlayout.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0.1dp" >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widgetBtn"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/wi_off" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        >
    </ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.flashlight"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service android:name="com.flashlight.CurrentService" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.dimrix.flashlight.CurrentProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
                </category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" >
                </category>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.flashlight.CurrentService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widgetproviderinfo" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.flashlight.StartScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: that is too general of a question to solve it here

Comment: still didnt solved the main problem . i will post a code ...

Answer (score 1):

I also made an app for flash light it  works fine and there is no time delay for Image change. so **Untill you don't post code it is very difficult to guess reason for your problem.**

For second issue you must be getting `!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!` when your widget freezez.It is a long running issue which many developer is facing.But you can avoid by using small size(memory) of images used in widget because Binder can take only small memory less then 1.5MB.I also faced same problem check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833156/why-my-widget-freezes-after-somedays).`Nobody was able to answer it`

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the Refresh interval `android:updatePeriodMillis` by using AlarmManager to alarm each interval you want.
may this [link](http://androiddevblog.blogspot.com/2012/03/repeating-update-on-appwidget.html) will help you.

Comment: i set the  android:updatePeriodMillis to 0 as sugested in the post but still a day after the widget not responding . 

the logcat shows after a day :

InputDispatcher - Delivering touch to current input target: action:0x0